# How to fix an output error in Python ? It keeps displaying 'None'

Tags: spyder, python-3.7

I've written a code for 20 Questions Game that should guess the number a user has selected from 1 to 100. But, it keeps displaying the same output again and again which is as given below. Please help me find the error.

**The Code is:**

```
a=1
b=10
for i in range(a,101):
    y=input(print("Is your number b/w",a,"to",b,"including both ? Answer Yes or No"))                                              
    if(y==Yes):
        j=a
        for j in range(a,b+1):
            x=input(print("Is your no.",j,"?"))
            if(x==Yes):
                print("Your number is",j)
            else:
                j=j+1
    if(y==No):
        break
    a=a+10
    b=b+10
```

**The Output looks like this**

> *Is your number b/w 1 to 10 including both ? Answer Yes or No*
>
> *None*

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at some examples online of how the input function is used and what it takes as a parameter.

The value None you are seeing is the return of the print statement.

Answer (score 0):

```
input(print("Is your number b/w",a,"to",b,"including both ? Answer Yes or No"))
```

Should be:

```
input("Is your number b/w " + str(a) + " to " + str(b) + " including both ? Answer Yes or No")
```

`input` accepts a string as a parameter, that gets printed. You passed `print` as the parameter.

Since `print` doesn't return anything, hence you get the output as `None`

Also, unless you have defined `Yes` and `No` as variables, they should be enclosed in single or double quotes:

Either this way (not recommended):

```
Yes = 'Yes'
No = 'No'
....
```

Or this way(recommended):

```
if y=='Yes':
    ....
```

You need to make changes in this manner for all your `input` and `if` statements.